# How to set cookie without response in "laravel"

Tags: cookies, laravel, response

I want to set cookie after doing all stuffs with this group of route
But when I use "before filter", it will return a response and then stop doing
Another thing.

What should I do?

This is my code

```
Route::filter('setcookie',function() {

    $test = Input::get('test',0);
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('cookie',Input::get('test'));     

    return Response::make(View::make('pages.home'))->withCookie($cookie);
});
```

---

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'setcookie'),function() 
{
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('pages.home');
    });

    Route::controller('productrest', 'ProductRestController');
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `Cookie::queue` function of laravel.

```
Route::filter('cookie',function(){
    Cookie::queue('key', 'value', 5);
});
```

From Laravel doc :

> Queueing A Cookie For The Next Response
>
> If you would like to set a cookie before a response has been created,
>   use the Cookie::queue() method. The cookie will automatically be
>   attached to the final response from your application.

http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies